# jquery selector problem?

Tags: jquery, colors

```
$('.lecture, .lecture > *:not(".meta")').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    var myCheckbox = $(this).children(':checkbox');

    if(myCheckbox.is(':checked')){
        myCheckbox.removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).closest('.vortrag').css({'background':'#F0F0F0'});
    }else{
        myCheckbox.attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).closest('.vortrag').css({'background':'#F8C1AC'});
    }  
});
```

can anyone explain why my .lecture div gets recolored when the checkbox inside of it is not checked, but when it's checked it doesn't get recolored.

So I have multiple divs with .lecture as a class. Inside of those divs are checkboxes. I want the entire div.lecture to trigger the checkbox when clicked (not just the checkbox itself). When a checkbox is checked the .lecture div should have a different background color. Everything works just fine. The checkboxes get checked and unchecked when i click the parent .lecture div. And it does even get recolored when i click it the first time. However once a checkbox is checked and i click it again to uncheck it the backgroundColor doesn't change again.

What could that be?

Comment: Give us your html structure as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkbox is an immediate child of `.lecture` then your second rule will target it.

But if you click right on the checkbox then the

```
var myCheckbox = $(this).children(':checkbox');
```

will return an empty jQuery object, because you try to find a ***child*** checkbox (and *`this`* **is** the checkbox)..

Please provide the actual html structure if you think this is not the issue ..